# coverage.py can't collect any data for coveralls failing in travis

Tags: python, python-2.7, travis-ci, coverage.py, coveralls

I am building a python application in travis. I have setup.py which basically runs the command:

```
py.test packageName
```

when we do: `setup.py test`

I am trying to run coverage plugin to push to coveralls so when i run the command:

```
coverage run setup.py test
```

it fails with :

```
running test
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected.
```

It is collecting all the test cases but just doesn't collect the data for some reason. My covezragerc looks like this:

```
> [run] omit = respawn/gen.py, respawn/cli.py, respawn/test/* 
> data_file = .coverage
```

Any reasons why ??

Answer (score 0):

I'll guess from the fact that you have "respawn" in your .coveragerc, that your product code is running in subprocesses.  Take a look at http://coverage.readthedocs.org/en/latest/subprocess.html to see how to configure coverage.py for that case.